# Render a file in a specific view mode

Tags: 7, files, media

Which is the right way to render a file in a custom view mode?
I'm using Media, 7.2 branch, I've custom view modes and I want to print in a tpl a file (based on fid) in the view mode "header_image".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use the [file_view_file()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!file_entity!file_entity.file_api.inc/function/file_view_file/7) function provided by the File entity module. The function has three parameters: a file object, the name of a view mode (or an array of custom display settings) and optionally a language code.

If you only have a file ID then you can do a file_load on the ID to get a full file object to pass to the function.

Note that file_view_file() returns a array as expected by [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) so, depending on how you are incorporating the file into your template, you may have to render the returned array using [render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7).

Comment: I needed to generate the render array and then use drupal_render in a preprocess this work great, thank you.